# setText not showing data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

My setText does not display any value from my Firebase. There is also no error showing for me to find the cause of the problem. Can someone show me where is the mistake that I miss? Any help would be really useful to me.

This is my XML coding.

fragment_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="628dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="BOOKING ROOM LIST"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/esearch"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:hint="Room No"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/readdataBtn"
            android:layout_width="261dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            android:text="SEARCH"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/esearch" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/readdataBtn" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/readdataBtn">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="MATRIX NO:"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvmatrix"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/readdataBtn">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="ROOM NO :"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvroom"
                android:layout_width="177dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="DATE : "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvdate"
                android:layout_width="164dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="TIME : "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvtime"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And here is my java coding.

DasboardFragment.java

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment{
    
        FragmentDashboardBinding binding;
        DatabaseReference reference;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
            binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            FragmentDashboardBinding binding= FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater);
            binding.readdataBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"PLease Enter Room Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    
                    String roomnum = binding.esearch.getText().toString();
                    if (!roomnum.isEmpty()){
    
                        readData(roomnum);
                    }else{
    
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"PLease Enter Room Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                }
    
    
    
            });
            return binding.getRoot();
    
        }
    
        private void readData(String roomnum) {
    
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Booking");
            reference.child(roomnum).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
    
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
    
                        if (((task.getResult()).exists())){
    
    
                            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                            String matrixNum = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Matrix").getValue(Booking.class));
                            String date = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Date").getValue());
                            String room = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Room").getValue());
                            String time = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue());
                            binding.tvdate.setText(date);
                            binding.tvmatrix.setText(matrixNum);
                            binding.tvroom.setText(room);
                            binding.tvtime.setText(time);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Successfully Load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    
                        }else {
    
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Room Doesn't Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        }
    
    
                    }else {
    
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
    
                }
            });
    
        }
    
    }
```

This is my JSON file from Firebase

```
{
  "Booking" : {
    "123456" : {
      "Date" : "22/4",
      "Matrix" : 124,
      "Room" : 2,
      "Time" : "11.00 am - 12.00 pm"
    },
   
    "BK20" : {
      "Date" : "22/5",
      "Matrix" : 123,
      "Room" : 3,
      "Time" : "12.00 pm - 1.00 pm"
    },
    "BK21" : {
      "Date" : "1/7/21",
      "Matrix" : 201302000,
      "Room" : "BK21",
      "Time" : "1.00 pm - 2.00 pm"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes..the Toast message "Succesfully Load" is display.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo but the setText was not showing anything.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have include my database structure.

Comment: As I see, you have multiple bookings under  `Booking` node, right? Do you want to get only one or all bookings?

Comment: @AlexMamo only one from it.

Comment: Ok, which one of them?

Comment: @AlexMamo can i get for BK20.

Comment: Before writing an answer, to understand better, you only want to get the data of `BK20`, right?

Comment: No... actually my coding was to search the id for the Booking child and display it..so if i enter BK20 , it will display all the item in it.

Comment: So if you call readData("BK20"), you can want to get the data only of BK20, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, to only get the content of "BK20", please use the following method:

```
private void readData(String bookingNumber) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference bookingNumberRef = rootRef.child("Booking").child(bookingNumber);
    bookingNumberRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                String date = snapshot.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                long matrix = snapshot.child("Matrix").getValue(Long.class);
                long room = snapshot.child("Room").getValue(Long.class);
                String time = snapshot.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", date + ", " + matrix + ", " + room + ", " + time);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then kick it off with:

```
readData("BK20");
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
22/5, 123, 3, 12.00 pm - 1.00 pm
```